# error #0 invalid controller name='xyz' format=''

Tags: php, joomla3.3

I have been working with Joomla! and there is this component I am making for the purpose of practice and I am getting these errors every time I try to run the component.
Any idea? The names of all classes and the format of the controllers are correct as I have gone over them and I have never stopped getting this error.

> error 0 invalid controller: name='xyz' format=''

Any help will be appreciated highly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the *component_name.xml and see if you have included all the folders and filenames residing in your base component directory for both site and admin parts respectively

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..
I misspelled `controller.php`... I had `contoler.php`.